# What is the best way to find what range a number is in?

Tags: java

I am working on a discount requirement, where the user should be given discount based on his order amount.

For example,

> Order 1000 to 5000 items - give 10% discount
>
> Order 5000 to 10000 items - give 15% discount
>
> Order 10000 to 15000 items - give 20% discount

These are the details I have in my database.

What is the best way to find the discount percent based on my order amount. I have tried setting these in a List of object and iterate them and find in what range it belongs and then get that percent.

But this seems to be a long approach. Please let me know if there is any better approach than this.

Comment: Is there a mathematical relation between the amounts and the discount%?

Comment: I would use a LinkedHashMap of key "Amounts" with value "Discounts". It's Linked so that it maintains order when you iterate over it, from highest to lowest. If your value is >= the iterated key Amount, apply the value Discount and break out of the loop.

Comment: If you have these details in your database, why not just look them up directly and skip the list / iterating section?

Comment: I'll cache these details from database and i have to look at my cache to decide the discount percentage

Comment: @EvanKnowles The question is, If i give you a number, what is the best way to find to which of the above ranges it belongs.

Comment: oh i just noticed there were in the DB… probably use some SQL :)

Comment: I'd let Hibernate or some other framework worry about the cacheing and go with a `SELECT discount FROM table WHERE price < maxPrice AND price > minPrice`

Comment: Yes to make it simple, my question is What is the best way to find what range a number is in? as @user1803551 said

Comment: oh, and you used the performance hashtag. how many billion discounts per second are you applying? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my Java solution. Totally agree if you want to do it direct with SQL. But either way, here's some codez! :)

I would use a LinkedHashMap of key "Amounts" with value "Discounts". It's Linked so that it maintains order when you iterate over it, from highest to lowest. If your value is >= the iterated key Amount, apply the value Discount and break out of the loop.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public void discount() {
    map.put(10000,20);
    map.put(5000,15);
    map.put(1000,10);

    System.out.println(discount(11000));
    System.out.println(discount(5100));
    System.out.println(discount(1100));
    System.out.println(discount(100));
}

private int discount(int value) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entrySet : map.entrySet()) {
        if (value >= entrySet.getKey()) {
            return entrySet.getValue();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Results… (it assumes that anything above 10000 is 20%)

```
20
15
10
0
```

Comment: When initializing your map: (1) It is recommended that the declared type (on the left side) is an interface. (2) No need to specify generic types on the righ hand side.

`Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>()`

Comment: Oops, yes. I usually use the base Map type. Just a "typo"

Answer (score 0):

Use the database. Assuming it's SQL:

Table `DISCOUNTS`

```
MIN    MAX    REDUCTION
---    ---    -------
1000   5000   10
5001   10000  15
10001  150000 25
```

SQL Query

```
select reduction
from discounts
where @amount between MIN and MAX
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a business app, you are going to write or just an example app?

In case, it is just an example app: 
Why not implementing a *fallthrough* method:

```
int getDiscount(int amount){
    if (amount >= 10000 && amount <= 15000) return 20;
    if (amount >= 5000) return 15;
    if (amount >= 1000) return 10;
    return 0;
}
```

**Pro**:

- it's easy to implement
- if there is a change in the group, it is easy adaptable

**Con**:

- it has too many magical numbers

*First refactoring:*

```
int getDiscount(int amount){
    if (isDiscountGroupA) return 20;
    if (isDiscountGroupB) return 15;
    if (isDiscountGroupC) return 10;
    return 0;
}

bool isDiscountGroupA(int amount){
    if (amount >= 10000 && amount <= 15000) return true;
}


bool isDiscountGroupB(int amount){
    if (amount>5000) return true;
}

bool isDiscountGroupC(int amount){
    if (amount>1000) return true;
}
```

**Pro:**

- better readable

**Con:**

- still has magic numbers in it.

*Second refactoring:*

```
public enum DiscountRanges {

    DISCOUNTGROUPAUPPERBOUND(15000),
    DISCOUNTGROUPALOWERBOUND(10000),
    DISCOUNTGROUPBLOWERBOUND(5000),
    DISCOUNTGROUPCLOWERBOUND(1000);

    private final int boundary;
    DiscountRanges(int boundary) { this.boundary=boundary; }
    public int getValue() {return boundary;};

}
```

So `DiscountRanges.GROUPCLOWERBOUND.getValue()` gives you the value for group C.

**Pro**:

- Magic numbers are encapsulated in an enum.

**Con**:

- none so far

*A JAVA8 solution:*

```
public class DiscountCalculator {

    Map<Predicate<Integer>, Integer> rules=new LinkedHashMap<Predicate<Integer>, Integer>();

    Integer getDiscount(int amount){
        Optional<Integer> o= rules
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(x->x.getKey().test(amount))
                .map(x->x.getValue())
                .findFirst();
        return (o.isPresent())?o.get():0;
    }

    public DiscountCalculator() {
        rules.put(x -> x >= 10000 && x < 15000, 20);
        rules.put(x -> x >= 5000, 15);
        rules.put(x -> x >= 1000, 10);

    }

}
```

**Pro**:

- since these are `lambdas` you are free to design complex predicate, not only checking bounds; e.g. you could include `modulo-arithmetic` to create more complex scales. Perhaps much nicer to code than to design a complex query.

**Con**:

*But* if these ranges are already in the DB, there is no need to hardcode them at all.

If you already have the conditions (in an easy queryable way) in the database, @Dave's answer suits your needs best: simply *select* it rom the DB.